# Select TOP X (or bottom) percent for numeric values in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, select

I was wondering if there are any functions that can be used in MySQL to select the TOP X(or bottom) percent from a column containing numeric values.

Basically, I have a column containing a list of prices and I only want to return those fields in the top ten percentile of prices. Any suggestions?

Comment: If only MySQL supported analytics -- NTILE specifically for this case, but ROW_NUMBER, DENSE_RANK, LEAD and LAG...  Your query has to calculate the percentile in a derived table/inline view in order to filter/order by it.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_ntile mysql 8 seems to support ntiles and other window functions now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE**: Much more thought-out explanation of the subject from much more knowing person [here](http://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=13620). Nonetheless, it still seems there's no *embedded* function in MySQL to calculate percentiles.

Try:

<strike>SELECT * FROM prices WHERE price >= (SELECT 0.9 * max(price) FROM prices)</strike>

```
SELECT price FROM prices p1 WHERE
(SELECT count(*) FROM prices p2 WHERE p2.price >= p1.price) <=
     (SELECT 0.1 * count(*) FROM prices)
);
```

This will give price *P1* for which number of records in *Price* table having *price >= P1*  will be one tenth of total number of records in *Price* table. 
After that:

```
SELECT * FROM prices WHERE price >= (SELECT price FROM prices p1 WHERE
(SELECT count(*) FROM prices p2 WHERE p2.price >= p1.price) <=
     (SELECT 0.1 * count(*) FROM prices)
);
```

will return all desired records.

**Note:** I didn't examine performance of this query, I think solution with temporary table/variable must be more effective.

Comment: This is not what "90th percentile" means... your query will select rows having prices of 90% of the highest priced item.

Comment: @Matthew you're right. I'm trying to figure out what's the diffrence :)

Comment: @Victor 90% percentile means "above 90% of the values"

Comment: Looks like this will cause 3 scans... seems a bit inefficient to me.

Comment: I reflected this in answer as well )

Answer (score 9):

### EDIT - new answer

Answered in [Convert SQL Server query to MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522433/convert-sql-server-query-to-mysql/5522462#5522462)

```
Select *
from
(
    SELECT tbl.*, @counter := @counter +1 counter
    FROM (select @counter:=0) initvar, tbl
    ORDER BY ordcolumn
) X
where counter <= (50/100 * @counter);
ORDER BY ordcolumn
```

---

#### OLD ANSWER

For MySQL, you could calculate the batch size required and then LIMIT to that number of records

```
SELECT @rows := ROUND(COUNT(*) * 10/100) FROM table;
PREPARE STMT FROM ‘SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY price LIMIT ?’;
EXECUTE STMT USING @rows;
```

For a bottom percent, just order in reverse

```
SELECT @rows := ROUND(COUNT(*) * 10/100) FROM table;
PREPARE STMT FROM ‘SELECT * FROM tbl ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT ?’;
EXECUTE STMT USING @rows;
```

Oops, maybe the DESC belongs in the first query, but you get the meaning.

*Note*
For SQL Server, the TOP N PERCENT clause certainly helps

```
select top 10 PERCENT *
FROM TBL
ORDER BY price
```

Comment: Neat trick, but isn't this is calculating the top 10% of rows by price, not all the rows in the top 10 percentile of price (which is what the question seems to be asking for per accepted answer; although it is a bit ambiguous)

Comment: Very nice indeed. @tardate for getting the top just ORDER BY DESC and  change 50/100 for 10/100..

Comment: Go back to the old answer!  Assigning @variables inside a `SELECT` is deprecated.  You have found one of the reasons for such.

Answer (score 9):

just as an FYI (i know this question is a few years old), this can be done other, cleaner ways as well.

```
SELECT * FROM product_table WHERE price >= (SELECT price FROM product_table 
ORDER BY price DESC LIMIT 1 OFFSET (SELECT 0.1 * COUNT(*) FROM product_table));
```

i ran a similar query over a very large database, and it ran very quickly.

Comment: Thanks, this just came in handy. What's the purpose of 'LIMIT 1'? Does that not limit the results to only 1 starting at the value of OFFSET?

Comment: the limit 1 will give you the exact value at 90%.

Comment: Is there a MySQL version of this answer?  I can't seem to get offset to take the value from the select statement, (SELECT 0.1 * COUNT(*) FROM product_table)

Comment: i don't have a MySQL install in front of me, but can you just subquery the count?  basically, select 0.1 * a.count from (select count(*) from product_table) a;

Comment: This doesn't work. The OFFSET part causes an error to be thrown :/