# Convert SQL Server query to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Select TOP X (or bottom) percent for numeric values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741239/select-top-x-or-bottom-percent-for-numeric-values-in-mysql)

How would I write this query in MySQL??

`SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT * FROM Persons`

The number of entries in the table will be constantly changing so I need to select by percentage rather than a fixed number.

Comment: @Sandro / see my answer for the real duplicate. The one you linked to is a straight TOP, not TOP X PERCENT

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is actually a [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741239/select-top-x-or-bottom-percent-for-numeric-values-in-mysql), but I now have a better, single-pass, fast, answer:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT tbl.*, @counter := @counter +1 counter
    FROM (select @counter:=0) initvar, tbl
    ORDER BY ordcolumn
) X
WHERE counter <= (50/100 * @counter)
ORDER BY ordcolumn;
```

Comment: Actually it's two passes (one from table, one from derived), but still O(N) rather than O(N^3), the accepted answer in the linked question. OTOH, my original answer in the duplicate works slightly faster, although it requires a batch rather than a single query.