# A query to generate 2 values based on the range of values of a column

Tags: mysql, sql

I've studied SQL many years ago but now my knowledge is very rusty. I will not post any code because my attempts didn't get even close. I am using MySQL.

if a have a table with products

```
product_id price
1           50
2           70
3           100
4           120
5           900
6           1100
```

I want to generate links like this on a web page

```
less than $70           //so that it narrows the result to ABOUT 30%
between $70 and $120    //so that it narrows the result to ABOUT 30%
more than $120          //so that it narrows the result to ABOUT 30%
```

I think I need a query that returns a minimum value a medium value

Using the example table, if the query returns a minimum value (70), 30% of the products will be bellow this value. A medium value, 30% of the products will be between the minimum value (70) and the medium value (120). Also 30% of the products will be above the medium value value (120).

This is roughtly my idea. I don't want a working code. I just want some example query that helps me to give me a "start".

Comment: What is the result you are looking for (as table - since SQL returns tables)? And what is your server version?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by

- Selecting the "middle" priced products and
- finding the **MIN** and **MAX** price

Use:

```
Select MIN(middleProducts.price) AS price30Percent, MAX(middleProducts.price) AS price70Percent
from
(
    SELECT products.*, @counter := @counter +1 AS counter
    FROM (select @counter:=0) initvar, products
    ORDER BY price
) middleProducts
where (30/100 * @counter) < counter AND counter <= (70/100 * @counter)
```

Use **price30Percent** & **price70Percent** to generate the links.

References

- [Select Top X records with mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522433/convert-sql-server-query-to-mysql/5522462#5522462)
- [Select TOP X (or bottom) percent for numeric values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741239/select-top-x-or-bottom-percent-for-numeric-values-in-mysql)

Answer (score -1):

You can start by using a "case" in the query, it should look like the following:

```
select `product_id`, `price`, case when price < 70 then 'less than $70'
                                when price between 70 and 120 then 'between $70 and $120'
                                when price >120 then 'more than $120' end as `Price category`
from `table`;
```

This way you will get a set of data showing the price category of every product, then you can arrange them the way you want.