# Partition data in Percentile range and assign different value for different Range

Tags: mysql

I have table structure as shown in below

```
Temp
 Customer_id | sum
```

Now I have to create view with extra column customer_type and assign value 1 if customer lies in top 10% customer (with descending order of sum,also total number of customer may vary) and 2 if customer lies between 10%-20%, 3 if customer lies between 20%-60% and 4 if customer lies between 60%-100%. How can I do this?

I just able to extract top 10% and between 10% - 20% data but couldn't able to assign value as ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741239/select-top-x-or-bottom-percent-for-numeric-values-in-mysql))

```
SELECT * FROM temp WHERE sum >= (SELECT sum FROM temp t1 
WHERE(SELECT count(*) FROM temp t2 WHERE t2.sum >= t1.sum) <= 
(SELECT 0.1 * count(*) FROM temp));
```

and (not efficient just enhance above code)

```
select * from temp t1 
where (select count(*) from temp t2 where t2.sum>=t2.sum)
>= (select 0.1 * count(*) from temp) and (select count(*) from temp t2 where t2.sum>=t1.sum)
<= (select 0.2 * count(*) from temp);
```

Sample data are available at [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bedbf/3)

Comment: Just my opinion but I don't think this is good use of a view. This has the ability to be a rather intensive operation and I wouldn't want it running every time someone accesses the view. Instead I would add a new table with this information, and populate it with a script in the wee hours each morning, so your data may not be real-time, but will be close enough and will be very efficient to grab when you need it.

Comment: @invertedSpear I agreed with you. But I'm currently doing data analysis, for which I create view(just for temporary)...

Comment: Maybe put up some sample data here http://sqlfiddle.com/ (50 records or so) and it might be easier to get help.

Comment: @invertedSpear I had added the data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had solve this as like this. Thanks for [@twn08](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716995/partition-data-in-percentile-range-and-assign-different-value-for-different-rang/16747695#16747695) for his answer which guide me upto this.

```
select customer_id,sum,case 
when pct_row<=0.10 then 1
when pct_row>0.10 and pct_row<=0.20 then 2
when pct_row>0.20 and pct_row<=0.60 then 3
when pct_row>0.60 then 4
end as customer_label from (
select customer_id,sum,(@curRow := @curRow+1)/c as pct_row
from temp t 
jOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
JOIN (SELECT @curRow2 := 0) r2 
join (select count(*) c from temp) s
order by sum desc) p;
```

I don't know whether this is efficient method or not but work fine for small data set.

Answer (score 2):

This should help you. You need to get row number for sum and total number of rows. I'm sure you can figure out the rest easily.

```
SELECT  
    *,
    @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number,
    (@curRow2 := @curRow2 + 1) / c as pct_row
FROM    
    temp t
    JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
    JOIN (SELECT @curRow2 := 0) r2
    join (select count(*) c from temp) s
order by 
    sum desc
```

This is based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126972/mysql-row-number)