# MySQL Median value by session length by group (hours)

Tags: mysql, sql, grouping, median, timestep

I need to calculate the median of user session length (ts_last-ts_first) by days (ts_first) in MySQL.
Trying something like this but it does not work.

Thanks!

```
SET @row_number:=0;
SET @medin_group:=’’;

SELECT @row_number:=CASE 
WHEN @median_group= FROM_UNIXTIME(first_ts, '%t') THEN @row_number+1
ELSE 1
END AS count_by_time,
@median_group:= FROM_UNIXTIME(first_ts, '%t') AS median_group,
FROM_UNIXTIME(first_ts, '%t') AS by_time,
AVG(last_ts-first_ts) AS length,
(SELECT 
              COUNT (*)
         FROM 
                  User_sessions
           WHERE 
                      a.by_time=by_time) AS total_by_time
FROM 
   (SELECT   FROM_UNIXTIME(first_ts, '%t') AS by_time, AVG(last_ts-first_ts) AS length
FROM 
     User_sessions
  ORDERS BY by_time, length) AS
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?  Variables are deprecated in the most recent version.

Answer (score 0):

To get the **Median value** of **duration**, "last_ts - first_ts", for table User_sessions(id, first_ts, last_ts):

```
Select MAX(totalSessions.duration) AS median
from
(
    SELECT User_sessions.last_ts - User_sessions.first_ts AS duration, @counter := @counter +1 AS counter
    FROM (select @counter:=0) initvar, User_sessions
    ORDER BY duration ASC
) totalSessions
where (50/100 * @counter) > counter
```

This works by:

1) Inner select: Assigning a incremental counter for each row of User_sessions ordered by duration,

```
lowest duration counter=1
2nd lowest counter=2
3rd lowest counter=3
```

2) At the end @counter = total rows of User_sessions.

3) An outer select, filters in the rows with **counter** < @counter.

References

- [Select TOP X (or bottom) percent for numeric values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4741239/4448410)