# SELECT TOP PERCENT, VaR, Expected Shortfall in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I would like to achieve **SELECT TOP PERCENT** in MySQL.

I used Victor Sorokin's idea in [Select TOP X (or bottom) percent for numeric values in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741239/select-top-x-or-bottom-percent-for-numeric-values-in-mysql), and got the following query:

```
SELECT x.log AS Login, 
       AVG(x.PROFIT) AS 'Expected Shortfall', 
       MAX(x.PROFIT) AS '40%VaR'
  FROM
  (SELECT t.PROFIT, 
          @counter := @counter +1 AS counter, 
          t.LOGIN AS log 
     FROM (SELECT @counter:=0) initvar, trades AS t
     WHERE t.LOGIN IN (100,101)
     ORDER BY t.PROFIT) AS x
  WHERE x.counter <= (40/100 * @counter)
GROUP BY x.log
```

Which return the following result:

| Login | Expected Shortfall | 40%VaR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | -85 | -70 |

This works when I change `WHERE t.LOGIN IN (100,101)` to a single value like `WHERE t.LOGIN=100`. Whereby it will return me values for each login as following:

| Login | Expected Shortfall | 40%VaR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | -4.5 | -4 |

| Login | Expected Shortfall | 40%VaR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | -95 | -90 |

I'm not really sure what is happening and I was wondering if there is a way to use the query for multiple accounts or there is a better way to solve the issue? Was thinking of a LOOP statement?

I'm currently using MySQL version 5.7.34. Please do not hesitate to let me know if any clarification is needed. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Edit: To replicate the issue:

```
CREATE TABLE trades (
TICKET int(11) PRIMARY KEY,
LOGIN int(11),
PROFIT double)

INSERT INTO trades (TICKET,LOGIN,PROFIT)
VALUES
(1,100,-5),
(2,100,-4),
(3,100,-3),
(4,100,-2),
(5,100,-1),
(6,101,-100),
(7,101,-90),
(8,101,-80),
(9,101,-70),
(10,101,-60),
(11,101,-50),
(12,101,500)
```

The expected output is just like the outputs you would get if you ran the query for 100 and 101 separately:

Expected Output

| LOGIN | ES | 40%VAR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | -4.5 | -4 |
| 101 | -95 | -90 |

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMPAV.png)

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67978388/edit) and provide a [Minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) .. e.g. sample data and expected output.

Comment: Assigning @variables inside a `SELECT` is deprecated.  You have found one of the reasons for such.

Comment: Thanks @FaNo_FN, I have edited the question and provided a reproducible example. Please note I have changed 1/100 * at counter to 40/100 * at counter to make the example minimal. Please let me know if there is anything else you would like me to clarify.

Comment: Okay... The solution I referred to was posted like 8 years ago so that is why. Thank you @RickJames

Comment: What MySQL version are you using? You can run `SELECT @@version` to check.

Comment: Server: version 5.7.34 ; Local: 8.0.21 @FaNo_FN

Comment: You mentioned that the query works on single login, I assume on the same data sets. Can you provide details about the query you use and the result you got when you do on single login?

Comment: Sure. I just used the query in the question, but changed the where clause to: WHERE t.LOGIN IN (100). And the output is 
LOGIN, E.S., 40%VaR // 100, -4.5, -4    -- The same with the expected output
Does it make sense?

Comment: Here take a look at this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4b484efb89bb3c321b4dd2335d818892

Comment: Wow, I think this would work - thanks for that @FaNo_FN But it seems like ROW_NUMBER is not supported "(" is not valid at this position. Possibly because the server version is still 5.7?

Comment: Yes, ROW_NUMBER() in MySQL only supported from v8 onwards and on MariaDB v10.2 onwards. I did a quick search and actually found a way to emulate the [adding ROW_NUMBER() to each group in older MySQL version](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/). I've tested it and it works, [see this fiddle update](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4c291366ef58acc955e3a4514a2f0547).

Comment: Thanks, @FaNo_FN. I figured a similar way from your previous fiddle. Now, how do I get this question reopened so that I can select your answer?

Comment: You'll need three votes to reopen, me and another person have already voted so you only need one more person with "open vote privilege" to vote.

Comment: I look forward to October 2023, when [MySQL 5.7 reaches its end-of-life](https://endoflife.date/mysql). Then we can tell people with this type of question, "you need to upgrade — really." Even sooner is [MariaDB 10.2's end-of-life](https://endoflife.date/mariadb), in May 2022.

Comment: @BillKarwin I wish I was in charge -- really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the end result was not according to the single value queries was caused by the `@row_number` assignment. Taking the base query (the subquery) to run alone will return the following results:

| PROFIT | counter | log |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -100 | 1 | 101 |
| -90 | 2 | 101 |
| -80 | 3 | 101 |
| -70 | 4 | 101 |
| -60 | 5 | 101 |
| -50 | 6 | 101 |
| -5 | 7 | 100 |
| -4 | 8 | 100 |
| -3 | 9 | 100 |
| -2 | 10 | 100 |
| -1 | 11 | 100 |
| 500 | 12 | 101 |

As you can see, the `counter` value that was generated using `@row_number` is giving a running number for all of the data in the table regardless of it's `log` value. The result below shows the differences with query that using a single `log` value:

| PROFIT | counter | log |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -5 | 1 | 100 |
| -4 | 2 | 100 |
| -3 | 3 | 100 |
| -2 | 4 | 100 |
| -1 | 5 | 100 |

Here you can see that if using `log=100`, you'll get a `counter` (@row_number) generated from `1-5` as opposed to it being generated from `7-11` in the combined `log IN (100,101)`. This is why `WHERE x.counter <= (40/100*v.ctr)` in the final query only take `log=101` because it's the only one matches the condition. What you're looking for is a `counter` value separated by `log`. On MySQL 8.0+ (or MariaDB 10.2+) that support window function, this can be done by using `ROW_NUMBER()`. However, since OP is using an older version, [I found a way to emulate](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/) the functionality of `ROW_NUMBER()` accordingly.

This is the final query generated:

```
SELECT x.log AS Login,
        AVG(x.PROFIT) AS 'Expected Shortfall', 
       MAX(x.PROFIT) AS '40%VaR'
  FROM
  (SELECT t.PROFIT,
    @row_number:=CASE
        WHEN @id = LOGIN THEN @row_number + 1
          ELSE 1 END AS counter,
    @id:=LOGIN ID, t.LOGIN AS log 
FROM trades t 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @id:=0,@row_number:=0) as n
ORDER BY LOGIN) AS x 
  JOIN (SELECT Login,COUNT(*) ctr FROM trades GROUP BY login) AS v
  ON x.log=v.login
  WHERE x.counter <= (40/100*v.ctr)
  GROUP BY x.log
  ORDER BY x.log;
```

And here is the [demo fiddle (inclusive of ROW_NUMBER())](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4c291366ef58acc955e3a4514a2f0547) on MySQL 8.0+ query.

Comment: Thanks again. I will ask for an upgrade.